# How to create a dns name in GCP and make it work for load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-load-balancer

I created a load balancer in GCP and wrapped the ip address with some dns name.
But when I hit the dns name, it does not work.

I verified at console and could see, 'cloud dns' section of gcp, having.

```
loadbalancergcp.example.com.    A   300 34.XXX.XX.XXX
```

Do we have to register these dns names somewhere?

I have worked on azure and aws but I have never faced such problem, since I am new to gcp and not able to understand what I am missing here.

Comment: in case this A record is meant to be public - it isn't, you can check it with dig or on [dnschecker](https://dnschecker.org/). Please note that Cloud DNS is not a registrar, in case you need to purchase this DNS name, it is not sufficient to just create a Cloud DNS entry.

Comment: @jabbson but how come in azure and AWS they were allowing us to create a dns and make it functional for load balancer? I think the same pattern should be followed by the GCP.

Comment: There is no standard for how how it should be, and you can totally purchase the domain name with Google, see the requirements [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#requirements). it should help.

Answer (score 0):

As jabbson stated, make sure the A record is public in case that's your objective. Otherwise you can follow the documented guide on how to [map a DNS name to an IP address on your Internal LB](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/dns-names).

In case you're trying to do this with a Global Load Balancer, and using a public record, note that Cloud DNS isn't a registrar. You can follow the documentation on [Registering a domain](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/register-domain), and then go through the stepped guide on [setting up a Cloud DNS managed zone and a resource record for your domain name](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart).

Afterwards, you can use the [Forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#forwarding_rules_and_addresses) feature for HTTP(S) LBs to use an IP address to be used in DNS records for your application and tie it to your LB.

Hope the sum of information can be of use to solve your scenario.